# How to generate headers functionally?

Tags: r, r-markdown

How can I generate a narrative functionally in RMarkdown? For instance, say I want to generate 3 headers like

```
##First
##Second
#Third
```

from a vector `c('First', 'Second', 'Third')`, then knit to pdf

Comment: Please give a bit more info, such as an example of how you'd like the output to look, if you're still looking for an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to knit to pdf, this solution calls on LaTeX within an R code chunk to create the headers as you requested. Just add this into an .Rmd file:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Ryan Runge"
date: "8/30/2017"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r eval=TRUE, results='asis' }
headers <- c('First', 'Second', 'Third')
cat(paste("\\section{",headers,"}"))
```
````

The output is:

[image]

And if you don't want the R code chunk to show in the pdf, just supply echo=FALSE in the code chunk options.

Answer (score 1):

You can reference a pre-defined list of headers in RMarkdown as follows:

````
```{r}
list_of_headers <- c("Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3")
```

This is an example.

### `r list_of_headers[1]`

Stuff under the first header

### `r list_of_headers[2]`

Etc

### `r list_of_headers[3]`
````

[image: Reference]

Comment: Probably my use of _programmatically_ was confusing. By programmatically I mean that everything (including formatting) should be produced with a function.